# How to use jsprit code on server

Tags: intellij-idea, jsprit

I am newbie in web development and trying to use jsprit (https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit) on my website where I can pass incoming orders location to jsprit and get the optimised path from my current location. I don't know how to install this code on server. Can someone please guide me. (I don't know how to use a code written in Intellij and tested on local server on actual server).

Answer (score 0):

Jsprit library don't have the web interface. It is [jsprit](http://jsprit.github.io/) is a java based, open source toolkit for solving rich travelling salesman.

There are lots of sample examples are given in Jsprit. You must download latest code from [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/releases).

It is maven project so there are pom file given inside jsprit. As you are using Intellij-Idea just open the pom file using Intellij. It will take some time to get dependencies. After that you can open jsprit-examples package and run some examples.

[graphhopper](https://www.graphhopper.com/) have web interface and it uses jsprit

If you want to use jsprit in your website you need to make web interface for this. I am also working on this.

Comment: Can you please share the architecture or github link for reference?